# Microsoft type-c speaker doesn't work when I'm connected via USB-C Hubs to Graphics Card

Tags: drivers, sound, kernel, microsoft

I'm using Microsoft type-c speaker on Linux with USB-C Hubs. When I'm connected via USB-C Hub to Graphics card it is showing some error message.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgNjN.png

Do you know this issue? Or you have any similar?

Distribution: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Architecture: amd64
Running kernel: linux-6.4.7
Kernel version: 6.4.7